# How to prove van aubel's theorem using elementary geometry

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

Is there any proof using elementary geometry of ${\bf van \  aubel}$'s theorem. The theorem states given a quadrilateral and 4 squares placed in 4 sides of the quadrilateral .lines connecting the centers of opposite squares intersect at right angles and the lines have equal length. Please help

Comment: What have you tried? What do you consider "elementary geometry"? Look at [section 3 of THE BEAUTIFUL GEOMETRIC THEOREM OF VAN AUBEL by Yutaka Nishiyama](https://ijpam.eu/contents/2011-66-1/7/7.pdf)

Comment: Thank you very much